# NativeScript Failed resolving method create on class okhttp3.RequestBody

Tags: nativescript, okhttp

I'm using NativeScript 6.0 with Angular 8.0 and trying to use the nativescript-http-formdata plugin and keep running into a dependency issue;

```
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method create on class okhttp3.RequestBody
```

Full Error;

```
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Taken picture
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Gallery: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/NSIMG_20190821_10221.jpg
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Saved: /data/user/0/org.nativescript.preview/files/NSIMG_20190821_10221_thumbnail.jpg
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.resolveMethodOverload(Runtime.java:1201)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: FILE: /data/user/0/org.nativescript.preview/files/NSIMG_20190821_10221_thumbnail.jpg
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Image saved successfully!
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method create on class okhttp3.RequestBody
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onActivityResult(NativeScriptActivity.java:54)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7282)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app...
```

I'm using the nativescript-http-formdata plugin to send a photo

```
async sendPicture(filepath, imageAsset) {
    var url = "http://localhost:9000/images/upload";
    var name = filepath.substr(filepath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    // Get bitmap of file
    const imageAndroidBitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);

    // Prepare the formdata
    let fd = new TNSHttpFormData();
    let param: TNSHttpFormDataParam = {
            data: imageAndroidBitmap,
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            fileName: 'test.jpg',
            parameterName: 'file1'
    };
    let params = [];
    params.push(param);
    try {
        const response: TNSHttpFormDataResponse = await fd.post(url, params, {
            headers: {}
        });
        console.log(response);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get the okhttp3 dependency installed in NativeScript.

What I've tried so far

- Did a 'tns update' just incase my packages were out of date.
- Installed nativescript-https as someone said it satisfies the okhttp3 dependency problem
- Installed nativescript-okhttp as it looks like the plugin I'm missing.

**Update: Add dependency to app.gradle**

Within /App_Resources/Android/app.gradle

```
// Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
dependencies {
  //    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
  compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.10.0'
}

// If you want to add something to be applied before applying plugins' include.gradle files
// e.g. project.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
// create a file named before-plugins.gradle in the current directory and place it there

android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Then I restarted my preview

```
tns preview
```

Still getting the exact same error message.

**Update: Use 6.0 branch of nativescript-http-formdata**

Clone repo

```
cd ~/code/nativescript
git clone https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata.git
```

Get 6.0 branch

```
cd nativescript-http-formdata
git co 6.0
```

Install plugin directory

```
cd ~/code/AssetManagementPrototype
tns plugin install /home/map7/code/nativescript/nativescript-http-formdata/src
```

Run in emulator

```
tns run android --device emulator-5554
```

Error;

```
ERROR in /home/map7/code/nativescript/nativescript-http-formdata/src/TNSHttpFormData.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /home/map7/code/nativescript/nativescript-http-formdata/src/TNSHttpFormData.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/map7/code/AssetManagementPrototype/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:838:23)
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/map7/code/AssetManagementPrototype/node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.js:28:26)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/map7/code/AssetManagementPrototype/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ ./app/home/home.component.ts 11:0-61 216:33-48
 @ ./app/home/home.module.ts
 @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
 @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts
```

**Update: Try nativescript-http-formdata demo**

This also failed, Ref: https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata/issues/19

Comment: are you able to solve this issue now?

Comment: @Narendra I'm still getting this issue. Just loaded up the 6.0 branch of nativescript-http-formdata and got a different problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that as dependency. For further reading you can refer [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0).

in Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in Gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.10.0'
```

or

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
}
```

As per the sample provided in their git repo, they adding in src/platforms/android/include.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
}
```

Comment: @Narvendra I've just put that line into my app.gradle in the dependencies area and restarted my 'tns preview' and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata/blob/master/src/platforms/android/include.gradle#L7

Comment: Does this mean it's already loaded when I use the nativescript-http-formdata and maybe it's not the problem? ie: Is this a bug in the nativescript-http-formdata rather than a dependency issue?

Comment: you can try `compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"` instead of using `complile group` in your app.gradle

Comment: I think the problem is this line: https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata/blob/9fe65a8402639a5be6b99eb5a6aae23369d179df/src/TNSHttpFormData.android.ts#L29

Comment: did you do tns clean build after adding dependency n gradle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198208/discussion-between-map7-and-narendra).